# About NetBeans And .jar File

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, jframe

Currently, I am doing a CS102 project. Since I am quite beginner, I made a Fitness Assistant which creates a exercise program and diet based on user inputs.

I created most of the GUI with Netbeans because it is easy. In my project, I needed to add quite a few images to the GUI panels (the pictures of exercises etc.) , which I put in the main directory of the project and in the code I added "picture.jpg" as their addresses. Also, I need to do a lot of txt read and write operations, and similarly, for the addresses of the txt files I added "textfile.txt" in the code, and add the txt files to the main directory of project, too.

In Netbeans when I press the run project, it works perfectly as Intented, without any issues. All pictures are shown, all txt's are read without any issue and outputs(the diet and the workout list) are added to the JFrames. By the way, in my project there are 3 different JFrames which will connected each other with buttons. First the welcome frame and start button, when the button is clicked; first panel becomes invisible and second ,the user input frame, becomes visible then when the users finishes the inputs they click a proceed button, then the third and last frame becomes visible and the input frame becomes invisible, and users can see their workout plan and diet created for them.

But the thing is, our instructor told us to make projects as some sort of executable which he will click on and run on his computer and it should work. However, when I built the .jar file from Netbeans, and tried to run it it does'nt work at all. First issue is when I clicked the button nothing happens, second frame does'nt open. (First frame becomes invisible). And also the .jpg pictures I added that works perfectly on Netbeans run project, are not shown. (I added all of the pictures with hard coding them in the code, not by right click/properties and add icon with Netbeans) Also I make .jar a .rar and look inside of it,inside of it there were no .jpg files and .txt files which are absolutely essantial for the way I wrote my code.

So, my question is, is there a way to make my project an executable (not neccesarily an .exe , anything that can work without netbeans installed is fine) (I know I have probably fu.. up everything when I add .jpg's and .txt's) Sorry for the long post, I hope you can understand it. And also, if you want to see the project file I can send it with PM's or something, I don't think I should add it here since it is an assignment.

Thanks.

TLDR: The .jar file created by Netbeans does not work as it works on Netbeans. .jpg's are not imported (which were on the main directory of the project), also opening a new jframe by a button does not work either. (Program runs completely fine on Netbeans)

Comment: Your post is too long, you only want to say that you can't export your images with netbeans as a jar.

Comment: And also, I wanted to say my second frame does not open in .jar even though it should.

Comment: You should edit as minimal as possible.. there is a lot of noise

Comment: Ok. I got it. All I need to do is putting all of my jpg's and txt's in the same direction with .jar file. I know it is quite a bad solution but it's better than nothing I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://jstart32.sourceforge.net/ This tool will turn your code into an exe but I'll suggest some not depending on this tool too much for future as it makes your java code which is basically a cross-platform thing into something that can run only on windows.

Answer (score 0):

To add images and txt file into .jar file you should make sure that, you have written complete path of image and txt file in code itself.(Like, C:/Folder/image.jpg)

---

Your second problem is your second jframe is not working.
So trick for that is, you have to run your all jframe's in Netbeans,make sure that all are running well,and then do clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

In `dist` folder, you will find three things :

1. the `.jar` file of your project
2. a `lib` folder
3. Readme.txt

Make sure that when you take your `.jar` file outside the project folder, take the lib folder as well.

The lib folder contains all the libraries, dependencies and jar files you've used in your project and are essential to make the jar file run.
Hope it helps!! :)